# Django objects.filter multiple filters

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

The user can select fields to filter by, I need to filter by only those fields but there can be 3 fields.

The user selects all three options:a, b and c

```
Foo.objects.filter(a=1,b=2,c=3), good
```

What if the user selects only 1 option or 2 options ?

```
Foo,objects.filter(a=1, b=2, c=not selected)
```

How can I do this to only filter by the selected choices. THis comes from a post to the view, and looks like this if not selected:

```
a=1,b=NaN,c=3
```

So b was not selected and I would not like to inlclude it in my filter,

```
Foo.objects.filter(a=1,c=3)
```

Or can I perhaps so a filter that is basically a "all" selector

So as per above:

```
Foo.objects.filter(a=1,b=%,c=3)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use a keyword argument dict:

```
filterargs = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3 }
Foo.objects.filter(**filterargs)
```

then to only filter on a and b:

```
filterargs = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2 }
```

or a and c:

```
filterargs = { 'a': 1, 'c': 3}
```